# Create a json from text+tsv file

Tags: bash, sed, jq

I am total beginner
Never Made a JSon In my life
Only parsed a few json
Text File:
**Number of Category may be varibale**

```
Category1
1111|2222|3333|444|5555
6666|7777|8888|9999|1111
0000|1111|22222|3333|4444
Category2
2222|3333||5555
2222|3333|4444||5555
Category3
AAAA|||BBBB
CCCC|DDDD|EEEE|FFFF|GGGG
```

Expected JSON:
Category ---> Arrays ---> For each tsv -->Make Key:Value(Year|Title|Name|Format|Base)
If tsv value not for anyone above add null
Json should be such that i can index each category numerically and reindex category to obtain tsv array

Json structure should be such that:
Eg.

```
1) I could get list of category using jq
cat file | jq
Output:
Category1
Category2
Category3
2) Index that Category
jq '.| Category[0]'
Output:
Category1
1111|2222|3333|444|5555
6666|7777|8888|9999|1111
0000|1111|22222|3333|4444


3) Index each tsv 
jq Category1 | jq '.[0]' ---> 
{
"Year": "1111"
"Title": "2222"
"Name": "3333"
"Format": "4444"
"Base": "5555"
}
```

jq '.| Category[0]

Comment: The data is too irregular. You mention five fields but not how to handle the data that does not have five fields.

Comment: Add null to ones not present

Comment: i cant even manaully create expected json. tried making object arrays but all errors

Comment: Show us what you've tried. We're helpful here but we should not be doing this whole job for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are too much freeform in your data for standard tools. I would suggest to use Perl like:

```
#!/bin/perl
use JSON::PP;

open(IN, "<file.tsv");
while(<IN>) {
  chomp;
  if (/Category1/) {
     $group = $_;
     @heads = ("Year", "Title", "Name", "Format", "Base");
  } elsif (/Category2/) {
     $group = "new name for Category2";
     @heads = ("Year", "Title", "Name");
  } elsif (/Category3/) {
     $group = $_;
     @heads = ("ABC", "EFD");
  } else {
     my @columns = split /\|/;
     my %row = ();
     for (my $i=0; $i < scalar(@heads); $i++) {
        $row{$heads[$i]} = $columns[$i];
     }
     push @{$data{$group}}, \%row;

  }
}
close(IN);

print encode_json \%data;
```

Comment: perl is a good tool for this but: 1. why change the field names (@heads array) for the different "categories"? The OP isn't asking for that. All categories have the same number of data fields, but some fields happen to be empty. 2. The presence of `|` distinguishes category lines from data lines. 3. Why hard-code the input filename? just use `while (<>)` and pass the filename on the command line (and as a bonus, the script also works on stdin without any extra code).  Also, bareword filehandles have been discouraged in perl for decades (and are disabled by default with `use v5.36.0` or later).

Comment: 1. read OP's sample data more carefully, it has different number of fields. 2. Maybe. You can make that improvement. 3. Just because. You can make that improvement. 4. I am still on 5.34. Then 5.36 will appear in ubuntu's repository, I change my habits, probably. You can make that improvement too. It is not a production script, it is a sample for showing concept.

Comment: 1. The OP's sample doesn't have a different number of fields on different data lines. They **all** have five fields, but some lines have **empty** fields.  An empty field still counts as a field.  Your answer does not actually answer the question, it answers your misinterpretation of it.  2. Regardless of what version of perl you're using, bareword file handles are bad practice.  As is the two argument version of open() - for safety, the mode should always be a separate arg from the filename.  Both have been discouraged for literally decades, but still supported for backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know what you expect the final JSON document to look like, but the following creates a JSON document, given your CSV input file, using Miller (`mlr`) and `jq`:

```bash
mlr --c2j -N --ifs pipe --ragged \
        label Year,Title,Name,Format,Base then \
        put '
                if (NF == 1) {
                        @Category = string($Year)
                } else {
                        $Category = @Category
                }' then \
        filter -x 'is_absent($Category)' then \
        unsparsify file.csv |
jq -n 'reduce inputs as $a ({}; .[$a.Category] += [$a])'
```

This first adds the headers you mention in the order you mention them in the question.  It then remembers the value of the `Year` field (the 1st field) if there's only a single field in the record.  The `Category` field is created with the remembered value if there are more than a single field.

We then remove all records that do not have the `Category` field, and we finish by adding empty values to any missing fields.

We now have a set of JSON objects:

```json
{ "Year": 1111, "Title": 2222, "Name": 3333, "Format": 444, "Base": 5555, "Category": "Category1" }
{ "Year": 6666, "Title": 7777, "Name": 8888, "Format": 9999, "Base": 1111, "Category": "Category1" }
{ "Year": 0000, "Title": 1111, "Name": 22222, "Format": 3333, "Base": 4444, "Category": "Category1" }
{ "Year": 2222, "Title": 3333, "Name": "", "Format": 5555, "Base": "", "Category": "Category2" }
{ "Year": 2222, "Title": 3333, "Name": 4444, "Format": "", "Base": 5555, "Category": "Category2" }
{ "Year": "AAAA", "Title": "", "Name": "", "Format": "BBBB", "Base": "", "Category": "Category3" }
{ "Year": "CCCC", "Title": "DDDD", "Name": "EEEE", "Format": "FFFF", "Base": "GGGG", "Category": "Category3" }
```

This is then processed by `jq`, which will collect the objects into arrays depending on the value in the `Category` field.

With the given data, this would produce something *equivalent to*

```json
{
   "Category1": [
      { "Base": 5555, "Category": "Category1", "Format": 444, "Name": 3333, "Title": 2222, "Year": 1111 },
      { "Base": 1111, "Category": "Category1", "Format": 9999, "Name": 8888, "Title": 7777, "Year": 6666 },
      { "Base": 4444, "Category": "Category1", "Format": 3333, "Name": 22222, "Title": 1111, "Year": 0 }
   ],
   "Category2": [
      { "Base": "", "Category": "Category2", "Format": 5555, "Name": "", "Title": 3333, "Year": 2222 },
      { "Base": 5555, "Category": "Category2", "Format": "", "Name": 4444, "Title": 3333, "Year": 2222 }
   ],
   "Category3": [
      { "Base": "", "Category": "Category3", "Format": "BBBB", "Name": "", "Title": "", "Year": "AAAA" },
      { "Base": "GGGG", "Category": "Category3", "Format": "FFFF", "Name": "EEEE", "Title": "DDDD", "Year": "CCCC" }
   ]
}
```

Passing this through `jq '.Category1[0]'` would give you

```json
{
  "Year": 1111,
  "Title": 2222,
  "Name": 3333,
  "Format": 444,
  "Base": 5555,
  "Category": "Category1"
}
```

Comment: Category is variable it just for example; can be any word Category may be Single, Duo, Group, anything

Comment: But i modified my tsv producing script so that it will prepend Category-to those lines.

Comment: Maycbe working in this tempate but not on actual file that has identical format, miller isnt productimg all key, value pairs

Comment: Only two key-value pair are formed

Comment: @TERRY Well, I can only test with the data I see.

Comment: The same data on my terminal produces : {
  "Year": "CCCC",
  "Title": "DDDD",
  "Category": "Category3"
}

Comment: @TERRY That means you're either not running the same commands that I use, or that your data is different from the data at the top of your question.

Comment: @TERRY I updated the answer to not rely on the string "Category" for the categories.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with `csplit` and `jq`.

You can split the data to temporary files like this:

```
csplit -z infile.csv '/^Category/' '{*}'
```

Convert `xx*` files to JSON objects:

```
for f in xx*; do
  <$f jq -sRrc '
  split("\n")
  | .[0] as $category
  | .[1:-1]
  | map(split("|"))
  | map({"Year"  : .[0],
         "Title" : .[1],
         "Name"  : .[2],
         "Format": .[3],
         "Base"  : .[4],
        }) | { ($category): . }
  '
done
```

Output:

```json
{"Category1":[{"Year":"1111","Title":"2222","Name":"3333","Format":"444","Base":"5555"},{"Year":"6666","Title":"7777","Name":"8888","Format":"9999","Base":"1111"},{"Year":"0000","Title":"1111","Name":"22222","Format":"3333","Base":"4444"}]}
{"Category2":[{"Year":"2222","Title":"3333","Name":"","Format":"5555","Base":null},{"Year":"2222","Title":"3333","Name":"4444","Format":"","Base":"5555"}]}
{"Category3":[{"Year":"AAAA","Title":"","Name":"","Format":"BBBB","Base":null},{"Year":"CCCC","Title":"DDDD","Name":"EEEE","Format":"FFFF","Base":"GGGG"}]}
```

You can get categories like this:

```
jq -r 'keys[]'
```

Output:

```
Category1
Category2
Category3
```

If you want a specific category, e.g.:

```
n=2; cat xx$(printf "%02d" $((n-1)))
```

Output:

```
Category2
2222|3333||5555
2222|3333|4444||5555
```

Fetch a specific entry by index, e.g. second object of `Category2`:

```
jq '.Category2 // empty | .[1]'
```

Output:

```json
{
  "Year": "2222",
  "Title": "3333",
  "Name": "4444",
  "Format": "",
  "Base": "5555"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON;
use strict;

my @fields = qw(Year Title Name Format Base);
my (%data, $category, $row);

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  my @line = split /\|/;

  if ($#line == 0) {
    # there are no field separators on this line, so
    # this must be a "category" line.
    $category = $_;
    $row = 0;

  } else {
    foreach my $i (0..$#fields) {
      # treat empty strings as null values
      undef $line[$i] if ($line[$i] eq "");

      $data{$category}[$row]{$fields[$i]} = $line[$i]
    };
    $row++;
  };
};

my $json = JSON->new->pretty->canonical;
print $json->encode(\%data) ;
```

BTW, 'pretty' enables line-feeds and indentation in the json string.  'canonical' causes the keys to be output in sorted order (otherwise they'll come out in semi-random order on each run because perl hashes are inherently un-ordered).  Both are disabled by default in the [JSON](https://metacpan.org/release/JSON) module because they incur extra processing overhead (i.e. they slow it down) and are only needed when a human is going to read the output - programs that process json data don't care about the order of keys.

Output with your sample data as input:

```
{
   "Category1" : [
      {
         "Base" : "5555",
         "Format" : "444",
         "Name" : "3333",
         "Title" : "2222",
         "Year" : "1111"
      },
      {
         "Base" : "1111",
         "Format" : "9999",
         "Name" : "8888",
         "Title" : "7777",
         "Year" : "6666"
      },
      {
         "Base" : "4444",
         "Format" : "3333",
         "Name" : "22222",
         "Title" : "1111",
         "Year" : "0000"
      }
   ],
   "Category2" : [
      {
         "Base" : null,
         "Format" : "5555",
         "Name" : null,
         "Title" : "3333",
         "Year" : "2222"
      },
      {
         "Base" : "5555",
         "Format" : null,
         "Name" : "4444",
         "Title" : "3333",
         "Year" : "2222"
      }
   ],
   "Category3" : [
      {
         "Base" : null,
         "Format" : "BBBB",
         "Name" : null,
         "Title" : null,
         "Year" : "AAAA"
      },
      {
         "Base" : "GGGG",
         "Format" : "FFFF",
         "Name" : "EEEE",
         "Title" : "DDDD",
         "Year" : "CCCC"
      }
   ]
}
```